# Giving a Prawn subtable a colspan

Tags: ruby, prawn

Is it possible to have a subtable span columns? If you try to style the table:

```
subtable   = pdf.make_table subtable_data, ...
table_data = [
                 [subtable, 'header 1', 'header 2'],
                 ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']
             ]
table = pdf.table table-data do |t|
    t.row(0).column(0).colspan = 2
end
```

You get:

> colspan must be provided in the table's structure, never in the initialization block.

And if you try to encapsulate the table in a cell:

```
table_data = [
                 [{content: subtable, colspan: 2}, 'header 1', 'header 2'],
                 ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']
             ]
```

It spans the cell correctly, but then renders the content as the default ruby object string:

```
#<Prawn::Table:0xblahblahblah>
```

Does anybody have another solution? Or must I create a subtable of every other row in that column?

Comment: This works ok for me (using `{content: subtable, colspan: 2}` as the cell contents). I can only reproduce it if I explicitly make `subtable` refer to a string by calling `to_s` on the result of the `make_table` call.

Comment: Doh. I had a procedure that checked cell contents and was calling to_s.